# Django - Using F() expression but obtaining non atomic update

Tags: python, django, django-models, race-condition

I have an admin action that looks like this:

```
def process(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for reservation in queryset:
        if not reservation.processed:
            reservation.processed = True
            reservation.save()
            item = reservation.item
            item.available = F('available') - reservation.quantity
            item.save()
```

So, the administrator can process a `reservation` of an `item`. Whenever he does, the `reservation` is marked as processed, and the number of available `items` is decreased by the quantity specified in the `reservation`.

As it happens for all admin actions, the admin can process multiple `reservations` at a time. Everything goes well if the `reservations` have all different `items`. But if two `reservations` share one `item`, the number of available `items` is only decreased by the amount specified in the last `reservation` processed.

I thought that `F()` expressions were just for this case: I want to make many changes to `item` and have them increase or decrease an attribute on `item` without running into race conditions. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you detecting this? Remember you have to call get() to get the new value...

Comment: I am looking at the value of item.available in the admin after processing the reservations! :-)

Comment: Do items get `select_related` in reservation queryset?

Comment: Why don't `Item.objects.filter(reservation=reservation).update(F('available') - reservation.quantity)` ?

Comment: @ilvar `reservation` has a foreign key to `item`, not the other way round

Comment: I think it might work with the reverse relationship. If not, you can do `Item.objects.filter(id=reservation.item_id).update(F('available') - reservation.quantity)`

Comment: If you post your models, we can give more accurate answers. Otherwise, `update(F('available') - reservation.quantity)` would work.

Comment: Curious if you ever got to the bottom of this or got a better understanding of it. According to django docs, it should work: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f . My own simple example works as I'd expect, but that is in a view method. Perhaps it is something about being done from the admin action, or maybe it was a bug that has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how you'd use the F object. Once you separate the steps of fetching from saving you're in essence making it explicitly non-atomic.

You should use `update` for that, so the *item* part should be:

```
Item.objects.filter(id=reservation.item.id).update(available=F('available')-reservation.quantity)
```

Or something similar.

Comment: The docs actually show this kind of use of F() expressions as the way to deal with a race condition just like shown in the question. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

Answer (score -2):

F() expressions are for use within a query, eg, when you want to do this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_col = bar_col
```

You'd do:

```
Foo.objects.filter(foo_col=F('bar_col'))
```

At any rate, your requirement that an item should only be decreased according to the last reservation made means that you have to get a bit creative with how you're looping through the reservations. One option would be to order the queryset by item id, and each time the id "changes", adjust the available amount based on that item's last reservation.

Comment: This is not actually true. F() expressions are used whenever you want to refer to a field on the same model. This can be done for various reasons, including comparison and updating. The code I posted **should** result in query to decrease `item.available` by `reservation.quantity`, rather than fetching the value of `item-available` and inserting it back changed. But apparently I am doing something wrong, as it does not work as expected

Comment: By the way, the fact that "an item should only be decreased according to the last reservation made" is the issue I am facing, not a requirement! It should be decreased according to all reservations, unless these are already processed

Comment: According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f, this is precisely one of the ways F() expressions can be used.